# Identify unicode characters that can't be printed

Tags: python, unicode, printing, character-encoding

I need to be able to determine (or predict) when a unicode character won't be printable. For instance, if I print this unicode character under default settings, it prints fine:

```
>>> print(u'\ua62b')
ꘫ
```

But if I print another unicode character, it prints as a stupid, weird square:

```
>>> print(u'\ua62c')
꘬
```

I really need to be able to determine before a character is printed if it will display like this as an ugly square (or sometimes as an anonymous blank). What causes this, and how can I predict it?

Comment: I'm not sure this is an easy thing to solve, it's dependent on the terminal being output to and probably the font that the terminal is using.

Comment: @DanielGibbs Ah! If this if font dependent, I should be able to parse the font information, right? Or choose a font with know limitations?  I should be able to determine known things about the terminal, as well. Though... what is it about the terminal that determines this feature?

Comment: Actually, it seems in your case that the problem might be that the character `\ua62c` isn't actually a valid Unicode character, so you can probably perform some sort of check for that first.

Comment: @DanielGibbs Ah, ha! Okay, this is a thing I didn't know about... so, some unicode IDs point to "invalid" characters? I didn't know that was a thing. Is there a way to check for validity?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While it's not very easy to tell if the terminal running your script (or the font your terminal is using) is able to render a given character correctly, you can at least check that the character actually has a representation.

The character `\ua62b` is defined as `VAI SYLLABLE NDOLE DO`, whereas the character `\ua62c` has no definition, hence why it may be rendered as a square or other generic symbol.

One way to check if a character is defined is to use the [`unicodedata` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unicodedata.html):

```
>>> import unicodedata
>>> unicodedata.name(u"\ua62b")
'VAI SYLLABLE NDOLE DO'
>>> unicodedata.name(u"\ua62c")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: no such name
```

As you can see above, a `ValueError` is raised for the `\ua62c` character because it isn't defined.

Another method is to check the category of the character. If it is `Cn` then the character is not assigned:

```
>>> import unicodedata
>>> unicodedata.category(u"\ua62b")
'Lo'
>>> unicodedata.category(u"\ua62c")
'Cn'
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the prompt response. And I learned something about Unicode. Looks like I have some reading to do. Thanks!